# Can someone review my implementation of an ArrayList?

Tags: java, array

```
public class ArrayList<E> implements List<E> {
    private static final int defaultMaxSize = 10;
    private int maxSize;
    private int size;
    private int currentPosition;
    private E[] array;

    /**
     * Create a new ArrayList object.
     *
     * @param maxSize
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public ArrayList(int maxSize) {
    this.maxSize = maxSize;
    this.size = this.currentPosition = 0;
    this.array = (E[]) new Object[this.maxSize];
    }

    /**
     * Create a new ArrayList object.
     */
    public ArrayList() {
    this(defaultMaxSize);
    }

    @Override
    public void insert(E item) {
    assert this.size < this.maxSize : "ArrayList capacity exceeded";
    for (int i = this.size; i > this.currentPosition; i--) {
        // Shift elements up to make room
        this.array[i] = this.array[i - 1];
    }
    this.array[this.currentPosition] = item;
    this.size++;
    }

    @Override
    public void append(E item) {
    assert this.size < this.maxSize : "ArrayList capacity exceeded";
    this.array[this.size++] = item;
    }

    @Override
    public E remove() {
    if ((this.currentPosition < 0) || (this.currentPosition >= this.size)) {
        return null;
    }
    E item = this.array[this.currentPosition];
    for (int i = this.currentPosition; i < this.size - 1; i++) {
        this.array[i] = this.array[i + 1];
    }
    this.size--;
    return item;
    }

    @Override
    public void clear() {
    this.size = this.currentPosition = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void moveToStart() {
    this.currentPosition = 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void moveToEnd() {
    this.currentPosition = this.size;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean previous() {
    if (this.currentPosition != 0) {
        this.currentPosition--;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean next() {
    if (this.currentPosition < this.size) {
        this.currentPosition++;
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
    }

    @Override
    public int length() {
    return this.size;
    }

    @Override
    public int currentPosition() {
    return this.currentPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public void moveCurrentToPosition(int position) {
    assert (position >= 0) && (position <= this.size) : "position is out of range";
    this.currentPosition = position;
    }

    @Override
    public E getValue() {
    assert (this.currentPosition >= 0) && (this.currentPosition < this.size) :
        "No current element";
    return this.array[this.currentPosition];
    }
}
```

And here is the List interface!

```
public interface List<E> {
    /**
     * Insert an element behind the current position. Must check that the linked
     * list's capacity is not exceeded.
     *
     * @param item
     *            Item to be inserted.
     */
    public void insert(E item);

    /**
     * Insert an element after the last element in the list.
     *
     * @param item
     *            Item to be appended.
     */
    public void append(E item);

    /**
     * Remove the element after the current element and return the value of the
     * removed element.
     *
     * @return The element that was removed.
     */
    public E remove();

    /**
     * Remove all contents from the list.
     */
    public void clear();

    /**
     * Move current position to first element.
     */
    public void moveToStart();

    /**
     * Move current position to last element.
     */
    public void moveToEnd();

    /**
     * Move the current position one element before. No change if already at the
     * beginning.
     *
     * @return True if moved to previous position; otherwise return false.
     */
    public boolean previous();

    /**
     * Move the current position one element after. No change if already at the
     * end.
     *
     * @return True if moved to current position; otherwise return false.
     */
    public boolean next();

    /**
     * @return The number of items in the list.
     */
    public int length();

    /**
     * @return The current position.
     */
    public int currentPosition();

    /**
     * @param position
     *            Position to move current to.
     */
    public void moveCurrentToPosition(int position);

    /**
     * @return The current item in the current position.
     */
    public E getValue();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- First and foremost : why are you writing this class? It doesn't look like an improvement or a specialized version of `java.util.ArrayList`.
- the `insert()` contract states : "Must check that the linked list's capacity is not exceeded." (wait, linked list?). You implement this with an `assert`. Yet asserts can be disabled. Don't use `assert` to honor the contract. It also is worth mentioning that the contract is unclear about what to do when the capacity is insufficient.
- `remove()`, `moveToStart()`, `moveToEnd()`, `previous()`, `next()`, `getValue()` and `currentPosition()` are things that belong on a `ListIterator`. This allows for more flexibility - having multiple iterators at the same time for instance.
- Since the underlying array does not grow when the original capacity is insufficient, your class adds little value compared to a naked array.
- naming wise the documentation talks about *capacity*, yet the implementation names it `maxSize`, it's better to name this field consistent with the documentation. There is a similar mismatch with '*length*' and '*size*'.
- `insert()` manually shifts elements, instead of using the more efficient `System.arrayCopy()` - the same goes for `remove()`.

Comment: I'd assume he's writing it just as a fun exercise for himself, not in an attempt to improve the existing API. :)

Comment: Ya it's just an exercise.

Comment: In that case, why don't you implement the `java.util.List` interface?